# Sending an Email with SendGrid

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am currently following a tutorial issued by SendGrid on how to send a basic email. The tutorial is provided here [Send Email Tutorial](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/#hello-email) on the "Hello Email" section.

In addition to this, I am following the [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEobqi3N7zw&list=PLMg--LMGA9rTvbCqbFafRqBBRYFksl7EZ&index=18) **which was suggest by SendGrid themselves**.

I have followed the tutorial to word for word, and am currently using the wamp64 server as the local host.

1. I have created a `config.json` file with no issues, as per the YouTube tutorial instructs, saved it to the wamp64 server, and is as follows:

```html
<?php

define('SENDGRID_API_KEY', '<my api key>');
```

2. I have created a `composer.php` file, as per the YouTube tutorial instructs, saved it to the wamp64 server, and is as follows:

```html
{

    "require":{

        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~7"

    }

}
```

3. I have downloaded the relevant files via Composer, as per the YouTube tutorial instructs, with no issues.
4. I have then created a `php` file, named it `test-email.php`, saved it to the wamp64 server and the code is as follows:

```html
<?php  

require_once 'config.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User"); //applying my email
$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("test@example.com", "Example User");//applying my email
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent("text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>");

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('SENDGRID_API_KEY');

try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}

?>
```

My file directory set up is as follows:

[Screenshot of file directory setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujt1f.png)

5. I then run `http://localhost/sendgrid/sendgrid/test-email.php` and hit enter. I get the error:

```html
401 Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [1] => Server: nginx [2] => Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2023 15:33:59 GMT [3] => Content-Type: application/json [4] => Content-Length: 88 [5] => Connection: keep-alive [6] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io [7] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST [8] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl [9] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600 [10] => X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html [11] => Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains [12] => [13] => ) {"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

Now my question is: what am I doing wrong and what am I missing here? No tutorial mentions anything about verifying SSL certifications nor creating environments?

I have tried to create an environment variable by altering the `config.json` with the following code:

```html
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env //using my API Key
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env
```

However, I get the following error message `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ';' or ',' in C:\wamp64\www\sendgrid\SendGrid\config.php on line 6`, which I don't really understand considering that there is not even a line 6 in the file, and that I have copied and pasted the exact code - except for inserting my own API Key - so the only explanation I can think of is that SendGrid need to alter their instructions.

I have tried adding ";" or "," but to no avail.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I haven't read the rest, but I see you use `new \SendGrid('SENDGRID_API_KEY');` to access the constant you defined. That's not going to work, you now access a constant containing `"SENDGRID_API_KEY"`. Try: `new \SendGrid(SENDGRID_API_KEY);` without the quotes.

Comment: @kikoSiftware bloody hell it really does go to show how awful the instructions from SendGrid are, they got me putting `SENDGRID_API_KEY` in `''` or `""`.  Any way, it's finally worked. If I can, I will mark your answer as the correct one. Many thanks.

Comment: Ignore the hassle of using SDK and just use the api directly. This may help you https://codecr8.com/2022/09/02/sendgrid-email-api-to-send-dynamic-emails/

Comment: I'm happy that it finally worked. That was a bit of struggle. Yes, I don't understand why SendGrid insists on using an environmental variable. It's quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use `new \SendGrid('SENDGRID_API_KEY');` to access the constant you defined. That's not going to work, you now access a constant containing *"SENDGRID_API_KEY"*. Try: `new \SendGrid(SENDGRID_API_KEY);` without the quotes. Like this:

```
<?php  

require_once 'config.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User"); //applying my email
$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("test@example.com", "Example User");//applying my email
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent("text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>");

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}

?>
```